# What kind of lock should I use when update and insert the same table?

Tags: python, mysql

I use MySQL's default engine `innodb` and MySQL's default transaction `REPEATABLE READS`.

My table `Job` has two fields, `job_id` and `queue`. Here are the data in it.

```
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| job_id                               | queue |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| 9f3ab652-dd2d-11ed-8cc5-d5f95fee8efd |     1 |
| c41fc700-dd2d-11ed-8cc5-d5f95fee8efd |     2 |
| d86ec674-dd2e-11ed-8cc5-d5f95fee8efd |     3 |
| 8e2b9c46-ddc8-11ed-a8b4-acde48001122 |     4 |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
```

Here I have `threads` modify the table. `update_func` is to reduce every row's queue value by one. `insert_func` is to insert a record based on the max queue value.

```
import uuid
import MySQLdb
import threading

conn = MySQLdb.connect("conn_info")
cursor = conn.cursor()


def update_func():
    cursor.execute("UPDATE job SET queue = queue - 1")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def insert_func():
    cursor.execute("SELECT max(queue) from job")
    max_queue = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    job_id, queue = str(uuid.uuid1()), max_queue + 1
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO job VALUES(%s,%s)", (job_id, queue))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=update_func)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=insert_func)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

After executing it, I got the following.

```
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| job_id                               | queue |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| 9f3ab652-dd2d-11ed-8cc5-d5f95fee8efd |     0 |
| c41fc700-dd2d-11ed-8cc5-d5f95fee8efd |     1 |
| d86ec674-dd2e-11ed-8cc5-d5f95fee8efd |     2 |
| 8e2b9c46-ddc8-11ed-a8b4-acde48001122 |     3 |
| ed910f36-ddc8-11ed-be60-acde48001122 |     5 |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
```

What I want is the queue are `0~4`. Here I got two questions.

1. what kind of `lock` should I use?
2. Do I have to use `transaction` when using `lock` as well?

Comment: this all seems very contrived; what is your actual use case? why do you need to update all rows, and why do you want to insert a new row based on a max value?  I suspect someone could guide you to a much more reasonable approach to handling your data.

Comment: @ysth For my project, I need to give a queue number for the user if he has to wait. The queue number is based on current max queue number. If a task finished, every task waiting in the queue can step forward. That's why I want to update all rows.

Comment: You asked virtually the same question yesterday. Don't re-post the same question. If you don't get the answers you are hoping for, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: sounds very much to me like you should not store queue at all, just calculate it as needed based on a timestamp

Comment: e.g. `insert into job (job_id, queue_time) values (%s,utc_timestamp())`, then `select job_id, count(previous_jobs.job_id) as queue from job left join job as previous_jobs on (previous_jobs.queue_time,previous_jobs.job_id) < (job.queue_time,job.job_id)`